# How to align the inequality sign?

Tags: equations, alignment

I have a hard time aligning the inequality sign? By what way can I solve the problem?

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1} 
\begin{aligned}
z = x + y  \leq 7^{o+1}\\
\implies x \leq 7^o + \frac{b}{7}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: `\begin{aligned}
z = x + y  &\leq 7^{o+1}\\
\implies x &\leq 7^o + \frac{b}{7}\\
\end{aligned}` Just insert alignment points (`&`) before the `\leq`s

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

The `&` ("ampersand") symbol is used in *all* multi-line display-math environments of the `amsmath` package capable of performing alignment -- `align`, `flalign`, `alignat`, `aligned`, `split` (both the starred and the unstarred variants) -- to denote the alignment marker. The character upon which alignment is supposed to be performed is often, but not necessarily, the equality symbol, `=`. To perform alignment on *inequality* symbols, you'd thus write:

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1} 
\begin{aligned}
z = x + y  &\leq 7^{o+1}\\
\implies x &\leq 7^o + \frac{b}{7}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```